# scraping table from a website result as empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the main table with tag :

```
<table _ngcontent-jna-c4="" class="rayanDynamicStatement">
```

from following website using 'BeautifulSoup' library, but the code returns empty [] while printing soup returns html string and request status is 200. I found out that when i use browser 'inspect element' tool i can see the table tag but in "view page source" the table tag which is part of "app-root" tag is not shown. (you see `<app-root></app-root>` which is empty). Besides there is no "json" file in the webpage's components to extract data from it. Please help me how can I scrape the table data.

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import unquote
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
yurl='https://www.codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=T1hETjlDjOQQQaQQQfaL0Mb7uucg%3D%3D&rt=0&let=6&ct=0&ft=-1&sheetId=0'
req=urllib.request.urlopen(yurl)
print(req.status)
#get response
response = req.read()
html = response.decode("utf-8")
#make html readable
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html")
table_body=soup.find_all("table")
print(table_body)
```

Comment: It's *scrape* **not** *scrap*.

Comment: @baduker yes, you are true. changed the words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table is in the source `HTML` but kinda hidden and then rendered by `JavaScript`. It's in one of the `<script>` tags. This can be located with `bs4` and then parsed with `regex`. Finally, the table data can be dumped to `json.loads` then to a `pandas` and to a `.csv` file, but since I don't know any Persian, you'd have to see if it's of any use.

Just by looking at some values, I think it is.

Oh, and this can be done *without* `selenium`.

Here's how:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=T1hETjlDjOQQQaQQQfaL0Mb7uucg%3D%3D&rt=0&let=6&ct=0&ft=-1&sheetId=0"
scripts = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(url, verify=False).content,
    "lxml",
).find_all("script", {"type": "text/javascript"})

table_data = json.loads(
    re.search(r"var datasource = ({.*})", scripts[-5].string).group(1),
)

pd.DataFrame(
    table_data["sheets"][0]["tables"][0]["cells"],
).to_csv("huge_table.csv", index=False)
```

This outputs a huge file that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @Vova, what do you mean?

Comment: anyway great solution, have not seen something like that!

Comment: Thanks, @Vova, appreciate it.

Comment: @baduker that was a good solution, I  did not find "datasource" variable in other places in sourcecode to be styled, which means the table is styled in server side. By the way, I could read the "table_data" and changed it to a nice format like what is displayed in web page.

Answer (score 0):

Might not the best solution, but with webdriver in headless mode you can get all what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument('--headless')
url = 'https://www.codal.ir/Reports/Decision.aspx?LetterSerial=T1hETjlDjOQQQaQQQfaL0Mb7uucg%3D%3D&rt=0&let=6&ct=0&ft=-1&sheetId=0'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(bs.find('table'))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I know about selenium, but it is a library useful for testing and simulation, I'm looking forward finding other ways.

Comment: I am not in hurry for the quick solution, if you find other better scraping method it is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the elements your're trying to get are rendered by some JavaScript code. You will need to use something like Selenium instead in order to get the fully rendered HTML.